# Does OpenJPA have any support for batch insert?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, openjpa

Does OpenJPA have any support for batch insert similar to [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)? I haven't found it in the docs, but I'm hoping I missed it. I know [JPA doesn't support it in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362972/portable-jpa-batch-bulk-insert).

Comment: I'm sure a simple Google search would answer that; "openjpa batch insert" perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

Longer answer, take the link to Hibernate documentation and replace the Session with a JPA EntityManager.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Transaction tx = em.getTransaction();

tx.begin();   
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    em.persist(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
em.close();
```